# Mysql LIKE query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

So I'm trying a basic query like this:

```
SELECT `City`.* FROM `city` WHERE (City 'LIKE %a%')
```

But I get this error in return:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your

MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''LIKE %a%') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

I guess I'm missing something out!

Comment: The syntax is `WHERE CITY LIKE '%a%'`

Comment: Put the single quote *after* the `LIKE`: `SELECT City.* FROM city WHERE (City LIKE '%a%')`

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT `City`.* FROM `city` WHERE (City LIKE '%a%')
```

You weren't using your single quotes correctly.

It is:

```
City LIKE '%a%'
```

Not:

```
City 'LIKE %a%'
```

Comment: Thank you I will accept it asap! Also thank you guys for the short comments